ATmega32U4 not appearing on Windows
I have made a custom PCB that contains a ATmega32u4-AU at its core. I have assembled the board, but when I connect it to my computer I am getting no response from it anywhere on my computer. It isn't appearing in device manager, not even as an unknown device.
Below is my schematic for the chip. It isn't shown, but I have a jumper to ground for reset and HWB is connected to ground.

I have confirmed that the chip is getting power, and that all of the pins are soldered to the board correctly.
When I connect to my computer I jumper between the reset and ground and then remove it, but the device does not appear anywhere in Windows 11. I'm running out of troubleshooting steps and would appreciate any help.

There's missing information that you have not told us. Do you have a bootloader? Have you installed any drivers? Have you plugged it into different USB ports?

Your USB pinout seems wrong. Assuming mini/micro USB, Pin 5 is GND not pin 4

Why do you expect it to appear when connected to PC? Which exact model you bought (order code), the one with or without the USB bootloader? How is the USB wired to PC?

You bought the U4RC variant.
It has the HWBE fuse unprogrammed so the HWB pin cannot be used to enter USB bootloader. It will also use the internal RC oscillator instead of the external crystal.
